# Serializing data to JSON with white space

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to pass data from cshtml file to my Javascript via data-* attribute. 
I'm using method like this

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json; 
@{ var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ListToPass); }
<div id="mainView"
     data-custom=@Html.Raw(list)>
</div>
```

which works okay in theory, but since some of my data, has values containing space, eg. "Name Something", my data is actually passed as

```
<div id="mainView" 
     data-custom="[{"Id":1,"Field":"Name">
</div>
```

What is the way to do this correctly?

Comment: are you finding any solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: I first create a variable in ``<script>`` tag, and from there I'm referencing it in my js file. It works but it not an elegant solution.

Comment: there is the elegant one :``<div id="mainView" data-custom='@Html.Raw(list)'></div>`` by adding ``'`` apostrophe to  ``@Html.Raw(list)`` that ignore the space in the html. works fine for me. if it's work for you, i can add it like an answer, so will help others.

Comment: Yes, it did help! Thank you!

Comment: i can move it to Answer?

Comment: Of course. I will mark it as correct

Comment: i'm adding the answer, please upvote and accept the answer, so that others would find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer as per comment validated by @MeeraWeeks:
**Solution**:

Adding `'` apostrophe to `@Html.Raw(list)` that ignore the space in the generated `html`.
The `div` tag will be:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json; 
@{ var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ListToPass); }

<div id="mainView"
     data-custom='@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(list))'>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have one more question. What if my data has ``'`` in it? Is there any way to escape it?

Comment: Hi, i will check this, and i come back to you.

Comment: to resolve the problem with ``'`` you can use ``HttpUtility.HtmlEncode``, then data will be ``data-custom='@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(list))'``, i hope this will help :)